# Why Sortable concept requires totally ordered value type, while std::sort only requires "less than" comparable?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-concepts

In the [latest paper on concepts N3701](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf), there is the following example with the `sort` algorithm:

```
template<typename Cont>
  requires Sortable<Cont>()
void sort(Cont& cont)
```

where `Sortable` concept is defined as

```
template<typename T>
concept bool Sortable()
{
  return Permutable_container<T>() && Totally_ordered<Value_type<T>>();
}
```

where `Totally_ordered`, not surprisingly, is defined as

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool Totally_ordered()
{
  return Weakly_ordered<T>() && Equality_comparable<T>();
}
```

and in turn `Equality_comparable` is defined as

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool Equality_comparable()
{
  return requires(T a, T b) {
    {a == b} -> bool;
    {a != b} -> bool;
  };
}
```

I didn't find the definition of `Weakly_ordered`, but I believe it should look like this (am I right?)

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool Weakly_ordered()
{
  return requires(T a, T b) {
    {a < b} -> bool;
    {a <= b} -> bool;
    {a > b} -> bool;
    {a >= b} -> bool;
  };
}
```

Bottom line, in this definition, if I want to sort `std::vector<T>`, I need T to provide *all* comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`. However, during the whole life of C++, `std::sort` only required operator `<` to be provided! Here is what [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) says about `std::sort`:

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order. The
>   order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved. The first
>   version **uses operator< to compare the elements**, the second version
>   uses the given comparison function object comp.

So what, does that mean that in future C++ with concepts, for `v` of type `std::vector<T>` where `T` provides only `operator<`, `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end())` will compile, while `std::sort(v)` will not? This sounds crazy.

I checked this in the current [ranges-v3 implementation](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) by Eric Niebler, and it works just like I described. Code does not compile unless all operators are provided.

See also related discussion: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/271

Answer (score 11):

The Concepts TS does not conceptualize the standard library. It was merely an example; nothing more.

The Ranges TS version of `sort` requires `Sortable`, which defaults its comparison class to `std::less<>`. However, it would seem that `std::less<>::operator()` imposes the `TotallyOrdered` requirement on the types of its parameters. So that's where it comes from. There's a note about this in [P0021R0 (PDF)](http://wg21.link/P0021R0):

> [Editor’s note: Remove table [lessthancomparable] in [utility.arg.requirements]. Replace uses of LessThanComparable with TotallyOrdered (**acknowledging that this is a breaking change that makes type requirements stricter**). Replace references to [lessthancomparable] with references to [concepts.lib.compare.totallyordered]]

Emphasis added. The general issues surrounding this [appear to be on-hold](https://github.com/ericniebler/stl2/issues/21), pending other language features (like implicit creation of all other operators based solely on `operator<` or somesuch).

You could simply use a (sane) version of a comparison function. Or you could just use the `std::sort` iterator version, which won't use concepts of any kind.

---

It should also be noted that, with [the introduction](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2017/11/20/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-albuquerque-november-2017/) of [the "spaceship operator"](http://wg21.link/P0515) in C++20 (the earliest we could see the Ranges TS integrated into the standard), this whole discussion effectively becomes moot. A simple `auto operator<=>(const MyType &) = default;` declaration in the class, and suddenly your type is totally ordered.

Comment: I checked this in the current ranges-v3 implementation by Eric Niebler (https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), and it works just like I described. Code does not compile unless all operators are provided. This implementation requires `IndirectCallableRelation` though.

Comment: Checking in from 2020. I wonder how we're supposed to pass a sort predicate that defines a total ordering.

Comment: @sehe: That's pretty simple: the `sortable` concept takes a callable which is a predicate that must impose [an `indirect_strict_weak_order` with regard to the value/reference types](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/indirectcallable.indirectinvocable#:indirect_strict_weak_order). Basically, it works the same as it always did. It's the default predicate `ranges::less` which imposes total ordering on the `T` and `U` it is given.

Comment: @NicolBolas that doesn't tell me anything about the interface. One `operator()` is not enough to specify less-than and equality comparisons. But I'll keep digging at `ranges::less`

Comment: Oh well. `ranges::less` is not a template. So, I'm "dead in the water" even if I can utilize a conversion of my type to some type T that has a total ordering defined. In general want to be able to specify alternative orderings for a value type, without changing the definition of that  type.

Comment: @sehe: You can do that. Just provide your own predicate. *Your predicate* isn't required to impose a total order, just a strict-weak order. If you don't use `ranges::less`, you don't have to deal with its ordering requirements.

Comment: Oh. Aha. This is ... weird. And helps. Simply start specifying `std::less<>{}` all over the place. Hmm. Not the best. Not the worst either. Thanks

Comment: @sehe: Do you consider the `operator<` overload of a type to be part of the type's definition? Because if you do, then `std::less` isn't going to help you "specify alternative orderings for a value type"; it will only let you use the `operator<` ordering of the type. I guess I just don't understand what you're trying to do if `std::less` is a solution, particularly in the context of C++20 where total ordering is pretty simple to achieve.

Comment: @NicolBolas I do not. Sometimes a natural default ordering can be part of the interface (hence `std::less<>`), but a good interface must be able to accept other ordering predicates. So, I'm a bit miffed why passing `std::less<>` (requiring strict weak ordering) is okay when range-lib requires total ordering. I bet it is just a random side-effect of concepts available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212039/discussion-between-sehe-and-nicol-bolas).