# Why is a std::list<int> not sortable?

Tags: c++, list, c++-concepts, c++20

I am just reading a (printed, German) article about C++ concepts (C++20 that is).

The article gives an example for a function template, using the `Sortable` concept:

```
template<typename Cont>
  requires Sortable<Cont>()
void sort(Cont& container) { ... }
```

And it claims that a compiler would reject the following code:

```
std::list<int> lst = { 1, 7, 5, 12 };
sort(lst);
```

with an error like:

> ERROR: lst is not random-access container with <

Assuming that the article is correct - why exactly is a **list** of **int** values not sortable? To me, a list of whole numbers is like the canonical example when thinking about something "sortable"?!

And no, I am not asking about **std::sort**. I am asking: why does the *concept* Sortable not work for a `std::list<int>`?

Comment: @DylanLawrence Are you sure? I am **not** asking about std::sort. But a **self defined** sort!

Comment: @GhostCat then it doesn't make sense unless the self defined sort was written in such a way as to require random iterators, in which case it's just a special case of why `std::sort` fails.

Comment: I've never seen `requires` before, and I just looked it up. It's C++20 feature?

Comment: @realharry it's part of the much anticipated concepts. Finger crossed it makes C++20.

Comment: @realharry I updated my question accordingly. Yes, C++20.

Comment: @DylanLawrence I do not follow you. The function uses the `Sortable` concept. I am asking why this concept doesn't apply to a list of int. I really don't see how that duplicated question is answering that.

Comment: @bolov It’s been merged into C++20, but I suppose they could un-merge it.

Comment: I'm with op on this one - Q: "Does `std::sort` work on `list<int>`?" A: "No as it would be ineffiecient.". Q: Is a `list<int>` _sortable_? A: It most definitely is.

Comment: Note that the most recent Ranges TS draft (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4685.pdf) defines `Sortable` to only require forward iterators.

Comment: @Rakete1111 although similar, this question deals with **c++20 concepts**, so I feel it is not a duplicate

Comment: @Rakete1111, *as the author and others point out*, this question is about concepts, and definitely not about `std::sort`. It’s possible, *but irrelevant to the question*, that the `sort` function defined in the article the OP was reading requires random-access iterators or is implemented by calling `std::sort`. But it is not `std::sort`, and there are sorting algorithms which work on non-random-access iterators.

Comment: @bolov But it's a bit like the same thing. This deals with the fact that `std::list` doesn't meet the requirements for `Sortable`, which is also how `std::sort` requires its range to be. The answer in both is "Sortable requires random access iterators, which std::list doesn't have".

Comment: @Rakete1111 more or less. Maybe more. But see Nawaz answer. It deals with defining your own concept, something which doesn't apply to the other questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> And no, I am not asking about **std::sort**. I am asking: why does the concept Sortable not work for a  std::list?

Well, it all depends on *how* you define the concept **Sortable**. So in the context of the text which you're reading, it is probably assuming that the *Sortable* container must operate on random-access-iterator — `std::sort` for example takes a pair of random-access-iterators; it *cannot* sort elements of container, say `std::list`, which doesn't support random-access-iterator.

However, that does **not** mean that you cannot define your own concept, say **FlexySortable** (along with an algorithm `flexy_sort`) that may operate on *non-random-access-iterator* as well. The text is simply giving **an** example of **a** concept to explain the general idea as to how *concepts* may help you to express your intent and your assumptions directly in the code which the compiler can verify by executing predicates (i.e the concepts).

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. More sense than the various "duplicates" that were put up by others.

Answer (score 3):

`std::list` is mostly a [doubly-linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list). So it obviously is not randomly accessible: accessing the n<sup>th</sup> element requires O(n) linear time (not constant, i.e. O(1)).

`std::vector` is randomly accessible; accessing the n<sup>th</sup> element requires constant time. So it has a random-access-iterator.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34619540/841108) is a related question.

Comment: This isn’t a question about `RandomAccessIterator` vs. `ForwardIterator` vs. `BidirectionalIterator`. It’s more related to the question you linked, but that’s still somewhat different.

Answer (score 2):

The `Sortable` concept is not defined in the language; you must define it yourself. Presumably it was defined earlier in the chapter?

Note that the [Ranges TS](http://wg21.link/ranges), which unlike concepts is *not* yet part of C++2a, defines a [`Sortable` concept](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ranges-ts/commonalgoreq#sortable). The only requirement that places on the iterators is from [`Permutable`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ranges-ts/commonalgoreq#permutable), which only requires `ForwardIterator`s.

Comment: Also helpful. No, the article just started using that concept, without giving any further details. Thus I assumed that *Sortable* is a common "standard" thing.

Comment: @GhostCat, when was the article written? The Ranges TS has been through a bunch of changes, and it’s plausible that an earlier version of `Sortable` did require a random access iterator.

Comment: This article is printed in the iX magazine - December issue. So it is brand new.

Comment: @GhostCat Then I have no idea. It's been that way for at least a year (it looks like it's probably longer, but I don't like GitHub's blame interface enough to find a specific change which might not exist) according to the Git history of https://github.com/ericniebler/stl2/blob/master/iterators.tex.

Comment: That's not the full story; the RAI requirement got pinned to `sort` itself (and friends) instead.